# How do I create a responsive two column layout using divs instead of tables?

Tags: html, css

**How do I create a responsive two column layout using divs instead of tables?**

The left div will have text and a call to action. The right div will have an image or is it better to have a transparent background and a png image?

I want both divs to be aligned and responsive. The divs should also stack on top of each other at different screen resolutions.

Below is what I've done so far. It's not perfect. Is there a way of cleaning this up so that I don't run into issues across multiple browsers.

Thank you.

```
<style type="text/css">*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
}

 .column {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
  }

 .center {
 padding: 50px 0;
  }

 .row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
  }

 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   .column  {
    width: 50%;
    }
  }


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column  {
  width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="column" style="background-color:#e0e620;">
<div class="center">
<p style="font-size:18px; ">The Information is now available as an audiobook.<br />
<a class="link-button-green" href="" title="Info guide">Listen now</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column" style="background-color:#E5E5E5;">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` instead of `float` to put the columns next to each other. In your `@media` query, you can remove `flex` for smaller screens so that the columns are displayed under each other.

The image width should be 100% of the flex column. The CSS doesn't have to be inline.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
    <div>The Information is now available as an audiobook.<br />
      <a class="link-button-green" href="" title="Info guide">Listen now</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column right" >
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex:1;
}

.left {
  background-color:#e0e620;
  padding:20px;
}

.right {
  background-color:#E5E5E5;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .row {
    width: 100vw;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLubao5d/1/

Comment: Thanks mate. How do I center the text within the div without ruining the div and image alignment? I want the text centered horizontally but left aligned. Will padding affect the div and image alignment? @Kokodoko

Comment: You can just add padding to the left column, or experiment a bit with different settings. I added the left column styling to the answer.